# Python logging framework

Tags: python, logging, microservices, filebeat, elk

I'm looking for recommendations on a python logging framework python within a microservice. There's the built in logging system provided by python, there's structlogger. Currently I use structlogger with an ELK stack with filebeat instead of logstash. Please let me know what you would recommend and why? My usual criterial is popularity on stackoverflow (I'm not kidding), as it makes it a lot easier to get over technical issues or bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Use the builtin `logging` module.

It does pretty much anything you need. `structlogger` isn't really a different framework and more of a default configuration for the builtin logging module. Also if you need something other than just logging to files or stdout the builtin module has a lot of handlers, and there exist a lot of third party handlers that work with the builtin module. (e.g. graylog)